# How to reduce a numpy array of spatial points with repetition allowed and sum intensity values

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a numpy array which contains arrays of [x,y,z,intensity]:

```
MyArray=np.array([np.array([1,2,3,.75]),np.array([1,2,2,.32]),np.array([1,2,3,.88])])
```

How can I possibly reduce the array to unique points while summing the intensity values when repetition occurs?

So that the final result from above would look like:

```
EndArray=np.array([np.array([1,2,3,1.63]),np.array([1,2,2,.32])])
```

I was thinking about using numpy.unique on the x,y,z's but that will give me integer counts of uniqueness and not consider the intensity column at all.

I'm sorry about the lack of code here, but I quite honestly don't even know where to begin outside of np.unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being NumPy tagged/processing NumPy arrays, we can use the new functionality of [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) that accepts `axis` argument for processing `2D` arrays as groups, to give us the intended output, like so -

```
In [51]: unq, tags = np.unique(MyArray[:,:3],axis=0, return_inverse=1)

In [52]: np.c_[unq,np.bincount(tags, MyArray[:,3])]
Out[52]: 
array([[ 1.  ,  2.  ,  2.  ,  0.32],
       [ 1.  ,  2.  ,  3.  ,  1.63]])
```